# ArrayList<Bitmap> doesn't take more than 50 elements?

Tags: java, android, arrays, bitmap

In my App I load some pics from the internet and store them into an `ArrayList<Bitmap>` so that the user doesn't have to reload them all the time. Now I saw that the **Arraylist** doesn't take more than 50 pics, after that my app crashes.

Is there any possibility to skip this border of 50?

Comment: you need to store it on the disk and you can have the path in arraylist.

Comment: Its not possible. Show us how you have intialized the List.

Comment: Can you post the Logcat output from the crash?

Comment: getting any outofmemoryexceptions?

Answer (score -1):

Normally no, the maximum capacity of an ArrayList (or any kind of list whatsoever) is limited only by the amount of memory the JVM has available.

Comment: Actually, the length of a List in Java is limited to 2^31-1 elements since an int is used as argument or result values in the API methods for e.g. random access or to get the list length.